# How to extract a substring from a .NET RegEx?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have an XML file containing one (or more) key/value pairs. For each of these pairs I want to extract the value which is a two-byte hex value.

So the XML contains this snippet:

```
<key>LibID</key><val>A67A</val>
```

Which I can match using the following expression, with the ID in parenthesis.

```
Match match = Regex.Match(content, @"<key>LibID</key><val>([a-fA-F0-9]{4})</val>");

if (match.Success)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Found Match for {0}\n", match.Value);
  Console.WriteLine("ID was {0}\n", "Help me SO!");
}
```

How can I change the last part so it returns the ID from the match?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I think you want

```
match.Groups[1].Value
```

(As Dillie-O points out in the comments, it's group 1 because group 0 is always the whole match.)

Short but complete test program:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
  static void Main()
  {
    Regex regex = new Regex("<key>LibID</key><val>([a-fA-F0-9]{4})</val>");
    Match match = regex.Match("Before<key>LibID</key><val>A67A</val>After");

    if (match.Success)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Found Match for {0}", match.Value);
      Console.WriteLine("ID was {0}", match.Groups[1].Value);
    }      
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Found Match for <key>LibID</key><val>A67A</val>
ID was A67A
```

Comment: Beat me to it. You're already using a grouped match there Andrew, so you can easily extract the grouped value. Oh, and for the record, index 0 contains the entire string, that's why you check index 1.

Comment: Super thanks. I knew it was in there somewhere, I just didn't know where :)

Comment: Hmm not sure why but my Match Groups contains only 1 value at index 0 which is the one I need. Anyway thanks

Comment: @CularBytes: Without knowing what pattern you're using or what you're matching against, there's no way we can explain the behavior to you. If you're interested in finding out more, please post a new question with a [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

Add a [grouping construct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah(VS.71).aspx) to your expression ...

```
<key>(?<id>LibID)</key><val>([a-fA-F0-9]{4})</val>
```

That will capture the ID.  But, you need to put the correct format in your expression for the actual ID, because your regex will only capture "LibID" litterally.

Comment: I think by "ID" Andrew means the contents of the <val> element, not the <key> element.