# .NET Regex - Specific String containing a changing number

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

I am new to working with Regexs in C# .NET. Say I have a string as follows...

```
"Working on log #4"
```

And within this string we can expect to see the number (4) vary. How can I use a Regex to extract only that number from the string.

I want to make sure that the string matches the first part:

```
"Working on log #"
```

And then exctract the integer from it.

Also  - I know that I could do this using  string.Split(), or .Substring, etc.  I just wanted to know how I might use regex's to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to extract a substring from a .NET RegEx?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/738543/how-to-extract-a-substring-from-a-net-regex)

Comment: This would be quite simple to find out yourself...

Comment: I looked through tutorials, and was having a hard time understanding the various explanations. I understand that it is simple, I just wanted to see how others might explain it. I appreciate your insight though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"Working on log #(\d+)"
```

The `()` create a match group, so you will be able to extract that section.
The `\d` matches any digit.
The `+` says "look at the previous token, match it one or more times" so it will make it match one or more digits.

So overall you're capturing a group containing one or more digits, where that group comes after `"Working on log #"`

Comment: Ah was just about to hit submit to send this in!

Comment: So \d results in an Unrecognized escape sequence, any thoughts?

Comment: in C# you'll  have to escape the `\`, so use `\\d`.

Answer (score 2):

`RegEx rgx = new RegEx("Working on log #[0-9]");` is the pattern you want to use. The first part is a string literal, [0-9] says that character can be any value 0 through 9. If you allow multiple digits then change it to `[0-9]{x}` where `x` is the number of repetitions or `[0-9]+` as a `+` after any character means 1 or more of that character is allowed.

You could also just do `string.StartsWith("Working on log #")` then split on `#` and use `int.TryParse()` with the second value to confirm it is in fact a valid integer.

Comment: This wouldn't catch 'Working on log #34'.

Comment: @MadSkunk that was true before I finished my edit :)

Comment: Indeed, consider my comment no longer valid :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `^(?<=Working on log #)\d+$`. This only captures the number. No need for a capture group. Remove `^` and `$` if this is within a larger string.

- `^` - start of string
- `(?<=)` - positive lookbehind - ensures what is between `=` and `)` is found before
- `\d+` - at least one digit
- `$` - end of string

Answer (score 0):

A capturing group is the solution:

```
"Working on log #(?<Number>[0-9]+)"
```

Then you can access the matched groups using the [Match.Groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.